# How to find the derivative of the inverse function $g^{-1}$, when no formula for the function $g$ is given?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $g$ is a strictly increasing function such that $g(7)=3$ and $g'(7)=7$, find $(g^{-1})'(3)$.

I'm not saying to just give me the answer. I want to understand what the problem is asking and how to do it. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You'll get a better response if you explain what your thoughts are about the problem, and what you've tried.  Are there any techniques you've learned recently that seem like they might help solve this problem?

Comment: i mean i know about the formula 1/f'(f^-1(x)), but im not sure how or if im supposed to implement it in this problem

Comment: That formula is definitely useful.  So what does that formula tell you $(g^{-1})'(3)$ is equal to?

Comment: it's exactly how jack explains it below. I knew alot of these formulas, but i needed that extra push to get me going.

Comment: I edited the question. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Also, in the future try to choose question titles that describe the actual mathematical question.

Comment: i apologize. i wasnt really sure on how to word it.

Answer (score 5):

Take $f$ as the inverse function of $g$ (it exists since $g$ is increasing). Then:
$$ f(g(x)) = x, \tag{1}$$
and assuming that $g$ is differentiable in a neighbourhood of $x=7$, then $f$ is differentiable in a neighbourhood of $g(7)=3$. By differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $x$ we get:
$$ g'(x)\cdot f'(g(x)) = 1, \tag{2} $$
and by "plugging in" $x=7$ we have:
$$ 1 = g'(7)\cdot f'(3) = 7\cdot f'(3), \tag{3}$$
so $f'(3)=\frac{1}{7}$.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. step by step instructions, so i could see how it's actually solved. that first formula f(g(x)) did cross my mind, but i wasnt to sure if it was used here. much appreciated Jack!

Answer (score 2):

$$
g^{-1}{'(3)} = \frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(3))} = \frac{1}{g'(7)}
$$

Comment: Could you please explain how $$
g^{-1}{'(3)} $$ is equal to $$\frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(3))} $$

Comment: @NonymousNT To derive that formula, start with $g(g^{-1}(x)) = x$ and differentiate both sides to obtain $g'(g^{-1}(x))(g^{-1})'(x) = 1$.  Now divide both sides by $g'(g^{-1}(x))$.

Comment: @NonymousNT : It follows from application of the chain rule to the identity $g(g^{-1}(x))=x$.  The original poster stated in a comment that he was aware of the fact that $g^{-1}{'}(x)=1/g'(g^{-1}(x))$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

One way of looking at inverse functions is that they are built by being mirrored about the line x = y. They are obtained by simply swapping x and y.

$$ g^{-1}{(3)} = 7 $$
$$ g^{-1}{'(3)} =\frac{1}{g'(7)} $$

Try to graph this function *and its inverse function* also, satisfying all conditions:

y(x) = 3 Cos(7) Cos(x) - 7 Cos(x] Sin(7) + 7 Cos(7) Sin(x) + 3 Sin(7) Sin(x)

Comment: @littleO. Thanks,typo corrected.